# Is this efficient way to use Nim ref data structure?

Tags: nim-lang

I'm keeping in memory huge list of companies, and need to do lots of operations of getting individual company.

Like getting individual company "Microsoft" by its symbol "MSFT".

Would the data structure below be a proper way to model that? There should be no copy-by-value of the whole `list` or `map`.

It is ok if the individual company would be copied by value.

```
import tables

type
  Company = object
    name:        string
    symbol:      string
    description: string

  CompaniesRef = ref object
    list: seq[Company]
    map:  Table[string, Company]

# Cached data structure to keep thousands of different companies
var cached_companies: CompaniesRef
proc companies(): CompaniesRef =
  if cached_companies == nil:
    # Here will be a proper code of loading companies into the 
    # CompaniesRef data structure
    cached_companies = CompaniesRef()
  cached_companies

# Lots of operations of getting a specific company from the list
# or from the map by its symbol
for i in 1..1000:
  # it's ok if individual company will be copied by value,
  # but the whole list should be passed by reference
  let company1 = companies().list[0].name

  # it's ok if individual company will be copied by value
  # but the whole map should be passed by reference
  let company2 = companies().map["MSFT"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That global structure should be fine as it is, an object reference is just a memory managed pointer, so passing its reference around only copies the memory address. Unless you are going to do something with that pointer, why not create it as a global? Hiding it behind a proc call reeks of the *I'm-afraid-of-globals-but-can't-live-without-them-singleton* pattern.

```
let companies = CompaniesRef()
```

With regards to the contents of the structure, you are storing twice each `Company` object, you might want to store a reference to the `Company` in the `Table` or simply use an [OrderedTable](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tables.html#basic-usage-orderedtable) if you need to keep the order of the inserted keys.

Comment: Thanks, good observation, I didn't realised that I store each company twice and can use ordered table :). As for globals - I'm using lazy load, loading those companies from disk takes some time, and I would like to avoid eager load and load it only if it's really used.